# Index Match issue in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, index-match

The error i keep getting is method 'match of object worksheet function failed. I have provided all the code below if anyone has an idea. I am trying to figure out simply to run this index match. I would like it to be pretty simple. Once i get this one it will be pretty easy to copy for the rest of my project

```
Option Explicit

Sub RunRecProcess()
'Variables
Dim LastRow As Long 'variable to count number of rows to use in for loop
Dim i As Integer 'counter variable to use in the For / Next Loop
Dim PropertyName As Range 'Salesforce Property Name
Dim SF_ID  As Range 'Salesforce transaction ID
Dim Panel_ID As Range 'Panel Transaction ID
Dim IndividualSF_ID As String 'single individual sf ID


'populating some variables
Set PropertyName = Worksheets("Salesforce Data").Range("A:A")
Set SF_ID = Worksheets("Salesforce Data").Range("D:D")
Set Panel_ID = Worksheets("Salesforce Data").Range("A:A")

'copying data over to backend sheet
    
    'pasting the Property transaction name
    Sheets("Salesforce Data").Select
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Backend Process").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "SF Property Transaction Name"
    
    'Copying and pasting SF Transaction ID
    Sheets("Salesforce Data").Select
    Columns("D:D").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Backend Process").Select
    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("B1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "SF Transaction ID"
    
    'Naming the first matching column
    Range("C1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Match to Panel ID"
    
    'initializing and providing value for LastRow and i
    LastRow = Worksheets("Backend Process").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    i = 1
    
    'Run for Next Loop to test if Panel has a corresponding Transaction ID
    For i = 1 To LastRow
        IndividualSF_ID = Range("B" & i + 1)
        Cells(i + 1, 3).Value = WorksheetFunction.Index(Panel_ID, _
        WorksheetFunction.Match(IndividualSF_ID, Panel_ID, 0))
        
    Next i
```

Comment: Seems like Match is not finding a hit - what type of data is in `Panel_ID`, and what type in `IndividualSF_ID` ?

Comment: They are both alphanumeric codes

f4525268-632d-4d0a-9622-731c1336fcda f4525268-632d-4d0a-9622-731c1336fcda

Comment: Oh it is working until I get to one where the match is not found. I need to add an on error resume. I figured it out thankyou